# A question about a particular homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

The unit circle $S^1$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ may be described as the set of points
$$\{e^{it}\;|\; 0\le t\le 2\pi\}.$$

Consider the following subsets of $S^1$: $U_1=\{e^{it}\mid -\pi<t<\pi \}$ and $U_2=\{e^{it}\mid 0<t<2\pi\}$.

> **Question 1.** How can I show that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open in $S^1$?

Thanks!

Comment: You should direct your efforts at sharing your attempts at solving the question, not merely copying it.

Comment: @uniquesolutionthanks for your comment. I know the rules of the forum very well, and if I didn't put my own attempt, it's because I don't have one, it makes me feel sorry for myself.

Comment: $U_1=S^1-\{-1\}$, $U_2=S^1-1$, points are always closed in metric topologies, hence the result by the definition of the open set as the complement of a closed set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^{it}$ is a homeomorphism,  in particular it is *open*.  That is, it takes open sets to open sets.  But, for instance,  $(0,2\pi)$ is an open set.